# Fetching posts from a page made only by the page using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I am trying to fetch all posts from a fan page using Graph API. I can do it in many pages using {page-id}/posts, but it does not work in all cases (example, facebook.com/cocacola). If I use {page-id}/feed, I can get it all, but I will get many user posts too. I could do it with FQL, but since FQL is not going to be supported anymore, I don't want to use it.

I want to get everything the page posts, even if it is a link, photo or share.

Something like this:

graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed?from.id={page-id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edge `/{page-id}/posts` will return all posts made by the page.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed

Comment: no, it doesn't. It returns nothing in most cases. For example:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Fposts&version=v2.0

Comment: Works well for me (http://cl.ly/image/1Q3K1v0D0S1m), where is the problem? Keep in mind that Pages may wish to limit the audience for their posts (geo-gating, age-gating, etc.). Also what the API returns must not 100% reflect what you see on the web.

Comment: For me it returns an empty list.. Damn.
Didn't know facebook had these types of limit. And it is weird, since I can get the posts calling by feed, but I would get a bunch of users posts together.

Thanks for the answer